# Couldn't locate expander in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, expander

I am having an expander than bind in the listview.

And I have another button to collapse/ expand all expander.

In code behind, I couldn’t locate the expander by using the code: `Expander exp = (Expander)listViewResult.FindResource("MyExpander");`

Any idea to do so?

```
<ListView Name="listViewResult" Margin="0,172,-10,-491" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
                      TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextElement.FontSize="12" 
                      Background="White" 
                      GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                      ……
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Expander Name="MyExpander" IsExpanded="False">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                                                <!--<ItemsPresenter />-->
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: try changing the name of the Expander it may get conflict with the Expander control of WPF.

Comment: @jadavparesh06 I have changed the expander name, but it still returns "MyExpander resource not found"

Comment: Use a VisualtreeHelper to find the expander control within your listview

Comment: Can you try Expander exp = (Expander)(this.FindName("MyExpander"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to expand/ collapse all expander, you could locate all the expanders by finding all child in the collection

**Calling the method:**

```
Collection<Expander> collection = FindVisualChild<Expander>(listViewResult);
foreach (Expander expander in collection)
{
     expander.IsExpanded = true;
}
```

**The Method:**

```
private static Collection<T> FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var children = new Collection<T>();
    FindVisualChild (current, children);
    return children;
}
private static void FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject current, Collection<T> children) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (current != null)
    {
        if (current.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {   children.Add((T)current);   }
        for (int i = 0; i < System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
        {
           FindVisualChild (System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i), children);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following method to find the controls within your Visual tree.

```
public static Visual GetDescendantByName (Visual element, string name)
         {
             if (element == null) return null;
             if (element is FrameworkElement
                 && (element as FrameworkElement).Name == name) return element;
             Visual result = null;
             if (element is FrameworkElement)
                 (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
             for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
             {
                 Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
                 result = GetDescendantByName(visual, name);
                 if (result != null)
                     break;
             }
             return result;
         }
```

where element will be your ListView and name will be name of the FrameworkElement you are looking for.

Comment: hi, your answer works fine. But I have several level of the expander (means under 1 expander will have another expander). 
When i apply : exp.IsExpanded = true, it only expand the first level.

Comment: Can you help to guide me to expand all level of expanders? thanks.

Comment: If you want all the expanders expander at the same time look for all the expanders within your frameworkelement rather than looking for a specific expander by name. search control by type as Expander and modify above method accordingly for collection of Expanders.

Comment: ok one more solution to expand all level of expanders is using Trigger to set the IsExpanded property of all the expanders to true or false based on your specific condition. Can you specify when all the expanders should expand and when they all should collapse??? Based on that we can create a specific style for all the expanders where we can have a trigger to set IsExpanded property true or false.

Comment: user can click on the "collapse/ expand all" button to collapse/ expand them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63142/discussion-between-jadavparesh06-and-user1850936).

Answer (score 0):

Try using x:Name property to define name for your expander and below code can help:
Expander exp = (Expander)listViewResult.FindName("MyExpander");

Comment: Hi Arushi, I have tried your answer, but it throws an exception of null reference.

Comment: null reference must be coming because listViewResult also needs to be defined using x:Name property